# What's the difference between stub.Predict.future and stub.Predict in tensorflow serving examples?

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I'm checking tf-serving examples and found that [inception_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py#L51) used `result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)` while [mnist_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py#L152) used `result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)`.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the names used to describe the return values of the two calls are different. `stub.Predict(request, 10.0)` makes a call that blocks until the RPC is complete and then returns the single response message of the RPC. `stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)` makes a call that immediately and without blocking returns a [`grpc.Future`](http://www.grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Future) for the happening-asynchronously-in-the-background RPC.